# R: Why do I get a Negative CH Index?

Tags: r, indexing, cluster-computing, ch

So, I'm trying to analyse my data following this tutorial :

https://enterotype.embl.de/enterotypes.html

At some point I need to determine the optimal number of clusters in my data calculating the CH Index. My problem is that sometime the CH Index come back negative and I think it's not even supposed to be possible normally ?!

[image]

[image]

Can you help me understand what is going wrong with the code and what can I change ?

Thanks all !

First I'm calculating the JSD distance using :

```
# CLUSTERING, Distance Metric


dist.JSD <- function(inMatrix, pseudocount=0.000001, ...) {
    KLD <- function(x,y) sum(x *log(x/y))
    JSD<- function(x,y) sqrt(0.5 * KLD(x, (x+y)/2) + 0.5 * KLD(y, (x+y)/2))
    matrixColSize <- length(colnames(inMatrix))
    matrixRowSize <- length(rownames(inMatrix))
    colnames <- colnames(inMatrix)
    resultsMatrix <- matrix(0, matrixColSize, matrixColSize)
        
  inMatrix = apply(inMatrix,1:2,function(x) ifelse (x==0,pseudocount,x))

    for(i in 1:matrixColSize) {
        for(j in 1:matrixColSize) { 
            resultsMatrix[i,j]=JSD(as.vector(inMatrix[,i]),
            as.vector(inMatrix[,j]))
        }
    }
    colnames -> colnames(resultsMatrix) -> rownames(resultsMatrix)
    as.dist(resultsMatrix)->resultsMatrix
    attr(resultsMatrix, "method") <- "dist"
    return(resultsMatrix) 
 }


data.dist=dist.JSD(data)
```

And then I'm trying to visualise the optimal number of clusters using :

```
# CLUSTERING, Optimal Number of Clusters

nclusters=NULL

    for (k in 1:20) { 
        if (k==1) {
            nclusters[k]=NA 
        } else {
            data.cluster_temp=pam.clustering(data.dist, k)
            nclusters[k]=index.G1(x = t(data), cl = data.cluster_temp,  d = data.dist,centrotypes = "medoids")
        }
    }
    
    plot(nclusters, type="h", xlab="k clusters", ylab="CH index")
```